# associative array with php

Tags: php, arrays, database, associative

I need to create an associative array with: date and number of events for that date.

Imagine this table (XPTO) in the database:

```
timestamp            id  parameter  sensor_id
2013-09-10 12:43:54   1   34           3
2013-07-23 10:32:31   2   54          65
2013-07-23 10:32:31   3   23          45
2013-07-23 10:32:31   4   12          1
2013-09-10 12:43:54   5   1           43
```

and now, the result that I want is the following:
[09.10.2013 12:43:54, 2], [23.07.2013 10:32:31,3].
Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does the trick.

```
$myarray = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp, count(id) FROM xpto GROUP BY timestamp");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $myarray[$row[0]]=$row[1];
```

If you want full information instead of counting:

```
$myarray = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xpto ORDER BY timestamp");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
    unset($row['timestamp']);
    $myarray[$timestamp][]=$row;
}
```

Now you have this array as a result:

```
[2013-07-23 10:32:31] => array (
                          array (
                              'id'=>2,
                              'parameter'=>54,
                              'sensor_id'=>65,
                          ),
                          array (
                              'id'=>3,
                              'parameter'=>23,
                              'sensor_id'=>45,
                          ),
...
```

Please modify following code based on your database connection type (PDO, etc)

Comment: But how do I create an associative array with the events that occur for a particular date?

Comment: I think I already answered this question by editing at the same time.